# Eclipse RCP - automatically shrink text in a TableViwer cell

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I'm developing my first Eclipse RCP application and I would like to know how can I force JFace TableViewer component to auto-shrink the text within a table cell. Right now, if I pass through the model a property which contains multi-line text, the text is displayed as is, which causes every row in a table to have different height:

[image]

What I want is just a single line, optimally if that line (if its too long to fit the cell) would be converted to something like 'Im a very very long lin...' and if the size of the window changes the line becomes 'Im a very very long line living in a...' where the full property is eg. 'Im a very very long line living in a table cell\r\n and some other text'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand exactly what you want.

If you are looking to remove the new-line's from the table cell text, you should do that using standard methods (String.replace()) before you set the cell text.

If you are looking to resize the column width to fit all the text, check out [TableColumn.pack()](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/TableColumn.html#pack%28%29).

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about the first option, I just thought that there is some flag I can set on the tableviewer / tableviewer column which does that automatically.

Comment: The cell is going to present whatever text the content provider gives it ... so if you want the text reformatted, you'll have to handle the reformatting yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I do as David suggested:

```
col.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
        @Override
        public void update(ViewerCell cell) {
            String desc = ((Product) cell.getElement()).getDescription();
            desc = desc.replaceAll("\\r\\n|\\r|\\n", " ");
            cell.setText(desc);
        }
    });
```